# Importing nested categories with Datagrab

Tags: categories, datagrab, import

Having difficulties importing nested categories from a CSV. Currently I have a single categories column, formatted as follows: 'parentcategoryname, subcategoryname'.

The subcategories all have unique URIs but their names are not unique. So, the subcategory with the correct name will be selected on import, but it will be under the incorrect parent category.

Is there a way to import nested categories, and I just have my CSV set up incorrectly?

EE version 2.9.2, Datagrab version 1.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Developer:

Use a slash ‘/‘ to separate subcategories, so you can do something like, 'Category / SubCategory'

The delimiter is hard-coded but if you want to change it is around line 1420 of models/datagrab_model.php:

$delim_cats = explode('/', $cat);